# check number of element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>
<p>2</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
</div>

<div>
<p>1</p>
</div>
```

How can I check if `<div>` have multiple `<p>`? if yes I want to keep the first `<p>` and remove the others `<p>` if any within the `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```js
$('div').find('p:gt(0)').remove()
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: do u know why Sagar's solution need a loop but yours does not?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var div=$('div');
 div.each(function(index,ele){
   var p=$(ele).find('p');
   console.log(p);
    p.first().siblings().remove();

   }); 
});
```

[Live DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/uv5ob39x/1/)

Comment: why u need to loop using each? I thought $('div') will select all `div`?

Comment: I think it is need when you need to perform a set of procedures for each div.

Comment: I have corrected and tested, We need to loop div because there are multiple divs and in each there are p, if it is the case of single div, no need to loop